# Polynomial function with 2 points

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Can someone please help me solve this problem ?

```
// please don't edit this away, my browser doesn't display all the special formated formulas
f (x) = ax^2 - bx^4 + 0.5
f'(x) = 2ax - 4bx^3
```

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f (x) = ax^2 - bx^4 + 0.5\\
f'(x) = 2ax - 4bx^3
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The function must:

- cross x-axis at $(3,0)$
- have a maximum at $x = 2$

I got $a = \frac59$ and $b = \frac{19}{18}$
Looks like the picture below. Something is wrong and the 2nd time I got false results as well.

[image: plot]

---

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
3^2a-3^4b+0.5=0\\
2\times2a-4\times2^3b=0\\\\
9a-81b+0.5=0\\
4a-32b=0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: When a curve cross the y-axis, then you have $x=0$. In your case $f(0) = 0.5$, so it cross the y-axis in the point $x=0$ and $y = 0.5$

Comment: @the_candyman Sorry, I wrote it down wrong. Happens sometimes when I think "y must be 0" and I write "cross y-axis". Corrected.

Comment: thus, you mean that the curve pass from the point (0, 3)?

Comment: Your solution of the linear system cannot be correct, as you should have $a=8b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solutions to your linear system are $$b=\frac{1}{18} \land a=\frac{4}{9}$$
And with this it seems right